# Extjs4, how to restore edited grid cell value in edit function?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to restore(set value to before edited value) edited grid cell value in edit function, not in validateedit function.

```
"orderList": {
    validateedit: function (plugin, edit) {
      //validate...
    },
    edit: function (plugin, edit) {
        Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure to change this order status?', function (btn) {
        if (btn == 'yes') {
            //update
        } else {
            // I want to rollback!
            edit.cancel = true;
            edit.record.data[edit.field] = edit.originalValue; //it does not work
        }
        });
    }
}
```

How to change the grid cell value (editor)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the [reject method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-reject):

```
"orderList": {
    validateedit: function (plugin, edit) {
      //validate...
    },
    edit: function (plugin, edit) {
        Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure to change this order status?', function (btn) {
            if (btn == 'yes') {
                //update
            } else {
                edit.record.reject(); // this should revert all changes
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also note that the second argument (the one you named "edit") of the `edit` event does not contain a `cancel` property, that is a property of the `beforeedit` event. So this line `edit.cancel = true` won't do anything for you.

I was also curious why you aren't using the `beforeedit` event, it seems more ideally suited for this kind of thing - that it why it does have that `cancel` property.

Comment: Note: this will reject all edits on a record, not just the only change coming through. If you want to reject only the current change on a single cell you should set the `originalValue` to the field. `e.record.set(e.field, e.originalValue)` -- at least when using `afteredit`

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to the `afteredit` event on the grid can do something like the following, depending on the granularity you would like to reset.

**Note**: I didn't add any logic to keep things quick and straight to the point.

### Reset Only the Current Change/Cell

```
grid.on('afteredit', function(e) {
  e.record.set(e.field, e.originalValue);
}
```

### Reset the Whole Record/Row

```
grid.on('afteredit', function(e) {
  e.record.reject();
}
```

### Reset the Whole Grid

```
grid.on('afteredit', function(e) {
  e.grid.store.rejectChanges();
}
```